# C++ inheritance, is it possible to have only 1 copy of a shared grandparent class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a project with some very small classes that act as minimal interfaces for larger classes.  Sometimes I have objects that need several of these interfaces.  And sometimes these interfaces share the same derived base class.  Is there anyway that I can structure my code so that I only have one copy of that derived base class that all of the interfaces share?

Here's a code example:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void f(int a)=0;
  virtual int g() const {
    return m_inner;
  }
protected:
  int m_inner;
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void f(int a)=0;
  virtual void h(int b) {
    m_stuff = b;
    m_inner = 0;
  }
protected:
  int m_stuff;
};

class C : public A {
public:
  virtual void f(int a)=0;
  virtual int i() const {
    return m_otherstuff;
  }
protected:
  int m_otherstuff;
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
  void f(int a) { //do stuff }
  //fill in the rest of a big actual class.
};
```

D has two copies of A and referencing A:: is ambiguous.  What's the best way to structure my classes so that I get only one copy of A at the end of the day?  I'm willing to restructure A, B and C in whatever fashion.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you considering making A be a virtual base?

Comment: It isn't clear why C would derive from A in your example.

Comment: I know, it was kinda fakey fake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual inheritance is what you need. Your case is a typical diamond problem. Have a brief search on google or any c++ book should give u plenty of related info

Comment: Today, I learned about the diamond problem and virtual inheritance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not much into C++ but I know this is called [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

and, [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual inheritance will solve your immediate problem (already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419943/virtual-inheritance)).
But, I strongly suggest you to re-think the hierarchy. I have never seen virtual inheritance used except in academic papers and in some cases of extreme refactoring. Perhaps, you may get away by using aggregation instead of inheritance.