# Multipath Inheritance and

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the following code the `Multi Path Inheritance` was resolved by using `Virtual Class`
How did the constructor work?
A Constructor cannot be inherited or virtual or static.

```
/*Multi Path Inheritance*/

class A{

public:
    int a;
    A(){
        a=50;
    }
};


class B:virtual public A{

public:
    /*B(){
        a = 40;
    }*/

};

class C:virtual public A{

public:
    /*C(){
        a = 30;
    }*/

};

class E:virtual public A{

public:
    E(){
        a = 40;
    }

};

class D : public B, public C, public E{

public:
    D(){
        cout<<"The value of a is : "<<a<<endl;  
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419943/virtual-inheritance

Comment: All constructors are called begining with base class up to the most dervived.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of informations and examples about virtual inheritance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcz57btd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (yes, it's actually on msdn, how strange :) )

As for the constructors, constructors get called as you specify them. If you don't specify a call for a virtua-base class constructor,

> constructors for virtual base classes anywhere in your class's
>   inheritance hierarchy are called by the "most derived" class's
>   constructor.

(read it [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Base on following quota from standard 12.6.2/10, so the constructor body will be called in following orde: A->B->C->D, so the final value of a will be 40.

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
> following order:
>
> ```
>  — First, and only for the constructor of the most
>    derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
>    they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
>    acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
>    appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>    base-specifier-list. 
>
>  — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>    declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>    (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> ```