# How to retrieve an inherited member function to override an interface definition - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, overloading, abstract-class

I'm trying to build a mini ORM in C++, and while attempting to implement SELECT, I thought that inheritance would be a good option to always be guided towards which function to use.

However, I'm having trouble getting a class to use the definition of a base class to override interface methods.

What I have currently done:

First, an interface that must define select:

```
    class ISelect : public IFrom
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ISelect() = 0;

        virtual std::unique_ptr<IFrom> from(const IEntityAlias &entity_alias) = 0;
    };

    inline ISelect::~ISelect() {}
```

Then the interface for FROM:

```
class IFrom
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IFrom() = 0;

        virtual std::unique_ptr<IFrom> leftJoin(
            const IEntityAlias &entity_alias,
            const IColumnName &lhs_column_name,
            const IComparisonOperator &comp_operator,
            const IColumnName &rhs_column_name) = 0;
};

inline IFrom::~IFrom() {}
```

Now I define these classes for the PostgreSQL SGBDR:

```
class From: public IFrom
        {
        protected:
            std::shared_ptr<PostgreSQL> _SGBDR;
            std::string _current_query;

        public:
            From() = default;
            From(const std::shared_ptr<PostgreSQL> SGBDR, std::string &&current_query);
            From(Form &&o);
            From(const Form &o) = delete;
            const Form &operator=(const Form &o) = delete;
            virtual ~From() = default;

            std::unique_ptr<IFrom> leftJoin(
                const IEntityAlias &entity_alias,
                const IColumnName &lhs_column_name,
                const IComparisonOperator &comp_operator,
                const IColumnName &rhs_column_name) override;
        };

class Select : public ISelect, public From
        {
        public:
            using From::From;
            using From::leftJoin;

            std::unique_ptr<IFrom> from(const IEntityAlias &entity_alias) override;
        };
```

So, my problem is that Select remains an abstract class because apparently, it does not retrieve the leftJoin definition from Form.

Therefore, my question is, how can I make Select not be an abstract class by inheriting from the Form class? Thank you.

I would like to be able to do:

```
ISelect *select = new Select();
select->from();
select->from()->leftjoin();
select->leftjoin();

IFrom *from = new From();
from->leftjoin();
/* 
from->from(); // NO
*/
```

Merci ! :)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419943/virtual-inheritance You have diamond inheritence without virtual inheritence

Comment: Here is your code with virtual inheritence to solve the diamond problem https://godbolt.org/z/xhb97vqe7. I propose to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I was not aware of the keyword before 'virtual' for inheritance.