# Understanding virtual inheritance on class declarations

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Suppose we have 4 classes:

- `Animal` - the grandparent class
- `Bird` & `Horse` - the parent classes
- `Pegasus` - the most derived class of both parent classes

When I declare the following:

Horse & Bird class declarations

```cpp
class Horse : virtual public Animal
{
// the Animal constructor and the Horse's constructor
}

class Bird : virtual public Animal
{
// the Animal constructor and the Bird's constructor
}
```

From what I understood, this means that that we should override the Animal constructor in the Pegasus class and whenever we initiate a Pegasus class, we automatically override the Animal constructor in both classes and we use the Animal constructor in the Pegasus class. I thought we don't call virtual on constructors though? Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: It might be useful https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order

Comment: The word "override" has a prescribed fixed meaning in C++. You cannot override a constructor. Only virtual functions can be overridden, and there are no virtual constructors. What you need to do is *call* the Animal constructor in the Pegasus constructor. Now, the call in the most-derived class constructor (i.e. Pegasus in this case) is used to initialize the Animal subobject, and the calls in the non-most-derived classes (Bird and Horse in this case) are ignored.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419943/virtual-inheritance

Comment: Please make a [mre].  Then, put some print statements in it.  Then run it and you will probably answer your own question.  If not, I'm sure the community will be pleased to help.  Just my $0.02

Comment: Although they both use the keyword `virtual`,  virtual inheritence and virtual functions are quite different concepts.   You're confusing the two.

Comment: I'm with @n.m.couldbeanAI here: this looks like a terminology problem. See also "initiate a Pegasus class"(_instantiate_), "I thought we don't call virtual on constructors" (?).