# What does it mean when "virtual" is in "class Foo : public virtual Bar" as opposed to "virtual void frob()"?

Tags: c++, virtual

I understand `virtual` in the context of a member function, like `virtual void frob()`. But what does it mean in the context of the class declaration, like `class Foo : public virtual Bar`?

For a given method there are 8 cases stemming from the presence or absence of virtual in the following three locations: 1) a superclass's functions; 2) the inheritance chain for this class; 3) this class's functions.

I think I understand how 1) and 3) interact, but 2) seems redundant. Is it? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's [virtual inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9), you do it when you know you'll be doing multiple inheritance. That page goes into way more detail.