# Virtual Inheritance Confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, virtual-inheritance

I'm reading about inheritance and I have a major issue that I haven't been able to solve for hours:

Given a class `Bar` is a class with `virtual` functions,

```
class Bar
{
    virtual void Cook();
};
```

What is the different between:

```
class Foo : public Bar
{
    virtual void Cook();
};
```

and

```
class Foo : public virtual Bar
{
    virtual void Cook();
};
```

? Hours of Googling and reading came up with lots of information about its uses, but none actually tell me what the difference between the two are, and just confuse me more.

Comment: I'm not going to answer because the subject matter doesn't really deserve such shallow treatment: but without `virtual` each class that inherits from `Bar` will have it's own copy of `Bar`, with `virtual` the most derived class will have only one copy of `Bar`.

Comment: Try: [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=virtual+inheritance+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ virtual base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-virtual-base-class)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840960/what-does-it-mean-when-virtual-is-in-class-foo-public-virtual-bar-as-oppos

Comment: It's used to avoid ambiguous calls when using diamond inheritance scheme (you probably already read this : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance is a useful page too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual inheritance is only relevant if classes are to inherit from 
`Foo`.  If I define the following:

```
class B {};
class L : virtual public B {};
class R : virtual public B {};
class D : public L, public R {};
```

Then the final object will only contain one copy of `B`, shared by both
`L` and `R`.  Without the `virtual`, an object of type `D` would contain
two copies of `B`, one in `L`, and one in `R`.

There is some argument that all inheritance should be virtual (because
in the cases where it makes a difference, that is what you want most of
the time).  In practice, however, virtual inheritance is expensive, and
in most cases, not necessary: in a well designed system, most
inheritance will simply be of a concrete class inheriting from one or
more "interfaces"; such a concrete class is usually not designed to be
derived from itself, so there is no problem.  But there are important
exceptions: if, for example, you define an interface, and then
extensions to the interface, the extensions should inherit virtually
from the base interface, since a concrete implementation could want to
implement several extensions.  Or if you are designing mixins, where
certain classes only implement part of the interface, and the final
class inherits from several of these classes (one per part of the
interface).  In the end, the criteron as to whether to inherit virtually
or not isn't too difficult:

- if the inheritance isn't public, it probably shouldn't be virtual
  (I've never seen an exception), otherwise
- if the class is not designed to be a base class, there's no need for
  virtual inheritance, otherwise
- the inheritance should be virtual.

There are a few exceptions, but the above rules err on the side of
safety; it's usually "correct" to inherit virtually even in cases where
the virtual inheritance isn't necessary.

One final point: a virtual base must always be initialized by the most
derived class, *not* the class that directly inherits (and declares that
the inheritance is virtual).  In practice, however, this is a non-issue.
If you look at the cases where virtual inheritance makes sense, it is
always a case of inheriting from an interface, which will contain no
data, and thus have (only) a default constructor.  If you find yourself
inheriting virtually from classes with constructors which take
arguments, it's time to ask some serious questions about the design.

Answer (score 5):

Functionality wise there is not much difference between the 2 versions. With the case of `virtual` inheritance, every implementation generally adds a (`vptr` like) pointer (same as in the case of `virtual` functions). Which helps to avoid multiple base class copies generated due to multiple inheritance (the [diamond inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_inheritance) problem)

Also, `virtual` inheritance **delegates the right to call the constructor of its base class**. For example,

```
class Bar;
class Foo : public virtual Bar
class Other : public Foo  // <--- one more level child class
```

So, now `Bar::Bar()` will be called directly from `Other::Other()` and also will be placed at the first place among other base classes.

This **delegation** feature helps in implementing a `final class` (in Java) functionality in C++03:

```
class Final {
  Final() {}
  friend class LastClass;
};

class LastClass : virtual Final {  // <--- 'LastClass' is not derivable
...
};

class Child : public LastClass { // <--- not possible to have object of 'Child'
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, no difference. Virtual inheritance is related to sharing superclass subobjects instances by derived classes

```
struct A
{
  int a;
};

struct B : public virtual A
{
  int b;
}

struct C : public virtual A
{
  int c;
};

struct D : public B, public C
{
};
```

There's a single copy of the member variable `a` in the instance of `D`; If `A` was not a virtual base class, there would be two `A` subobjects in instance of `D`.

Comment: "_In this case, no difference._" until you try to use `static_cast`!

Answer (score 0):

Virtual function is a function that will probably have different implementation in derived class (although it's not a must).

In your last example is virtual inheritance. Imagine a case where you have two classes (A and B) derived from a base class (let's call it 'Base'). Now imagine a third class C derived from A and B. Without virtual inheritance, the C would contain two copies of 'Base'. That could lead to ambiguity while compiling. The important thing in virtual inheritance is that the parameters for the 'Base' class constructor (if any) MUST be provided in the class C, because such calls from A and B will be ignored.

Comment: "_That could lead to ambiguity while compiling._" this **will** lead to an ambiguity _iff_ you try `C` IS-A `Base`.