# what is virtual inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Suppose I have this code:

```
class A {
};
class B: virtual public A {
};
class C: virtual public A {
};

class D: public B,public C, virtual public A {
};
```

If `D` inherits `B` and `C`, virtual inheritance can ensure there is only one copy of `A` contained in `D`; but what if `D` inherits `A` using `virtual public A` again, like in the code above?

Will there be one sub-object of type `A`, or two?

---

I am still confused about some expressions with virtual inheritance.
for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    A() {std::cout<<"A ";}
};

class B: A {
    public:
    B() {std::cout<<"B ";}
};

class AToo: virtual A {
    public:
    AToo() {
    std::cout<<"AToo ";
}
};

class ATooB: virtual AToo, virtual B {
    public: 
    ATooB() {
    std::cout<<"ATooB ";
}
};
```

can the `virtual` keyword ensure that there is only one copy of `A` in `ATooB`? if `AToo` inherits from `A` using virtual inheritance, but `B` does not, what will happen? Will there be two copies in `ATooB`? Does this imply that both `B` and `AToo` should use virtual inheritance for `A` in order to ensure that `ATooB` has only one copy?

Comment: edited my answer in repose to your editing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One - that's the intended use of `virtual` inheritance. There is only one copy of `A`.

You can actually verify that easily. Give `A` a member and modify it using a `D` instance. If there was more  than one copy of `A`, the compiler would say that the access is ambiguous.

**Edit** in the edited question, there will be two copies of A. Each time `A` is inherited regularly (without `virtual`), a fresh copy of A is made. If you want one copy, declare it `virtual` every time.

Answer (score 4):

From standard docs., *10.1.4*,

> ... For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, **the most derived object**
>   shall contain a single base class subobject of that type. ....

And so yes, just one.