# Why is "virtual" keyword used there?

Tags: c++

While Simulating final Class in C++, why is "virtual" keyword used?
C++ program without any compilation error to demonstrate that instances of the Final class can be created

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Final;

class MakeFinal {
private:
    MakeFinal() { cout << "MakeFinal constructor" << endl; }
    friend class Final;
};

class Final : virtual MakeFinal {
public:
    Final() { cout << "Final constructor" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Final f;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related to [what-is-virtual-inheritance-in-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910301/what-is-virtual-inheritance-in-c)

Comment: there is no need to simulate a final class. C++ has final classes https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: In the particular example you have given there is no point to using `virtual` inheritance.   However, in a scenario with multiple inheritance (e.g. your `Final` and a `Final2` that both inherit from `MakeFinal`, and then another class that inherits from both `Final` and `Final2`) the difference can be significant.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419943/virtual-inheritance), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class) and [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910301/what-is-virtual-inheritance-in-c).

Comment: I thoroughly checked the duplicates, and I did not find a question that is about the most derived class needing to call the virtual base constructor, nor mentioning the use to make a class final. Hence after careful consideration, I came to the conlusion that the question here is not fully answered by the duplicates and voted to reopen.

Comment: @Peter I thought the same initially. The point of `virtual` in the example is to prevent other classes inheriting further from `Final`.

Answer (score 3):

With virtual inheritance the most derived class must call the constructor of the virtual base class (in contrast to non-virtual inheritance where each class constructs its direct bases). Because `MakeFinal`s constructor is `private` and only `Final` is a friend, no other classes can access `MakeFinal`s constructor. Consequently you cannot derive from `Final`. More accurately you can derive:

```
struct OK : Final {};
```

but you cannot create instances, because constructing a `OK` would require to call the private `MakeFinal` constructor:

```
OK not_ok; // error: use of deleted function 'OK::OK()'
```

Without virtual inheritance this wouldn't work as intended, because then `OK`s constructor would call `Final`s constructor which in turn calls `MakeFinal`s constructor. All would be fine. Only with virtual inheritance the most derived class must call the virtual base class constructor.

---

Note that since C++11, this "simulation" is not required. There is [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) to explicitly make a class final.

---

> [...] without any compilation error to demonstrate that instances of the Final class can be created

Not sure if this is a misunderstanding. Of course you can create instances of a final class. When a class is final you just cannot inherit from it any further. (As explained above in your "simulation" one can inherit from `Final`, its just pretty useless because no instances can be constructed of a class inheriting from `Final`).