# base class constructs five times

Tags: c++, class, constructor

This "base" class constructs for b , medium1 and medium2. When i use "top" class, it construct 2 times more. Totally constructing 5 times(writing to screen 5 times).

**Question:**  What can i change in the "base" class to make it construct only once and for all.?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdlib.h> 

class base
{
public:
    base(){x=5;printf(" %i ",x);}
    int x;
}b;

class medium1:public base{}m1;

class medium2:public base{}m2;

class top:public medium1,medium2{};


int main() {
    top ten;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

what are pitfalls of virtual base class? Thanks for answering my trivial question.

Comment: 1- `m1` , 2 - `m2` , 3 - `b`,  4,5 - `ten` due to inheritance from `medium1,medium2`

Comment: Virtual base classes won't get the constructor count down to 1. There are four objects whose types are `base` or a type derived from `base`, so the least you can get is four constructions.

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: Your question has no meaningful answer. It is not possible to have it constructed only once. If you meant something else from what you actually asked, please, clarify your question.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want all of them to use only the original constructed base

Comment: If you want all those objects to use the same member `x`, just make `x` a `static` member.

Comment: For example: base gets a timer data. All classes uses that same time data. Not the different times

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: Independent objects cannot share one common base subobject. The language has no such feature. So, as long as you implement the concept of "inheritance" through language feature known as "inheritance", you will have at least 4 separate bases (since you have 4 independent objects).

Comment: Then i have no other questions. Thank you all

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: One way to go is to make timer data `static` in the case class. You will still have many bases (4 or 5), but all these bases will share the same timer data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to have `base` construct only once instead of all five original constructions. You have *four* complete objects in your program that contain `base` subobjects. This immediately means that regardless of what you do, you will have at least *four* `base` constructions.

Additionally, the suggestion to use virtual inheritance mentioned in other answers will actually require making changes to *other* classes, not to `base` class. Meanwhile your question insists that changes shall be made to `base`.

Comment: i made medium 1 and medium2 virtual and decreased to 4 constructions. yes you are right

Answer (score 5):

This will construct `base` only once when you create a `top` class.

```
class medium1:virtual public base{};
class medium2:virtual public base{};
```

The rest come from the fact that you create objects `b`, `m1` and `m2`. You can't really prevent calling the destructor of the base class because, well, **that's what you tell the compiler to do**. If you don't want to create `base` objects, don't derive from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a [`virtual` base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class), but that comes with a [giant](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-abcs.html) [set](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html) of [pitfalls](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm).

Comment: what are pitfalls of virtual base class?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single `base` class object if you use virtual inheritance:

```
class medium1:virtual public base{}m1;

class medium2: virtual public base{}m2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets you down to two calls, but I think since you have double inheritance that's the best you'll get.  If you eliminate the variable `b` in your `base` definition then you're there.  http://codepad.org/pn016D7b

```
#include<stdlib.h> 

class base
{
public:
    base(){x=5;printf(" %i ",x);}
    int x;
}b;

class medium1:virtual public base 
{
public:
    medium1():base(){};
};

class medium2:virtual public base{};

class top:virtual public medium1,medium2{};


int main() {
    top ten;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```