# What is the use of virtual base class in multilevel inheritance?

Tags: c++, virtual, base-class, multi-level

This was an exam question.

> Write a program demonstrating the use of virtual base classes in
>   multilevel inheritance.

I cannot think of any scenario in which a virtual base class would actually make any difference in the **specific case of multilevel inheritance**.

The only **possible answer** to the question i can think of is to show hybrid inheritance(the diamond) which contains multilevel inheritance in it.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: "I cannot think of any scenario", then "I can think of this one answer"... So, what is the question?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: *This was an exam question: Write ...*

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, I assume they mean multi-level multiple inheritance - the concept which you describe as the diamond.

Comment: @Elemental i assumed the same :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your question. The answer is the case with the diamond.
For the reason and why to use see this question:
[In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)