# Implementing pure virtual functions with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

Suppose there is this interface:

```
class A{  
 public:  
  virtual foo()=0;  
};
```

And a class `B` which implements this interface:

```
class B:public A{    
 public:   
  virtual foo(){} //Foo implemented by B   
}
```

Finally, a class `C` which has classes `A` and `B` as base classes:

```
Class C : public A, public B {
};
```

My question is, there is a way to tell the compiler that the implementation for `foo` is the one from class `B` without doing an explicit call to `B::foo()`?

Comment: Why would you want to do it a different way? The only thing you'll get out of that is more confusion in your code.

Comment: I don't want to do a wrapper to all pure virtual functions derived from the interface. Instead i want to use the implementation from the concrete class. There is a way to do this without these wrappers, or i have to do on wrapper for each function to call the implementation from the concrete class?

Comment: Right now, `B` doesn't implement that interface.  Did you intend `class B : public A` ?

Comment: Yes, i intended to. I edited the question =) Thank you

Comment: Your accepted answer is non-portable code which only works in g++, and only because of a compiler bug.  You might want to rethink that.

Comment: @DanielSaad I encourage you to "unaccept" my incorrect answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BenVoigt pointed out in the comments, the below answer only works due to a bug in g++ (meaning it isn't guaranteed to keep working, and it definitely isn't portable).  Thus, although it may do what you want if you use a particular (buggy) compiler, it isn't an option you should use.

*Do* use [virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21558/1214731) though.

---

This isn't exactly the scenario that the *code* in the question implies, but the sentence

> My question is, there is a way to tell the compiler that the
>   implementation for foo is the one from class B without doing an
>   explicit call to B::foo()?

seems to be asking for syntax to distinguish between multiple base versions of a function without using the `::` qualifier.

You can do this with the `using` directive:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
A(){}
virtual void foo(){std::cout<<"A func";}
};

class B: virtual public A {
  public:
  B(){}
  virtual void foo(){std::cout<<"B func";}
};
class C:virtual public A, virtual public B {
    public:
    C(){}
    using A::foo; // tells the compiler which version to use
                   // could also say using B::foo, though this is unnecessary
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.foo(); // prints "A func"
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the code itself in the question doesn't require this at all, as the other answers have pointed out.

Comment: This doesn't work without virtual inheritance, and isn't needed with virtual inheritance.

Comment: BTW, this is a g++ bug.  It should print "B func" according to the Standard.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hah, thanks for pointing that out.  I learned something there. I'd already +1'd your answer, so I can't do it again... I'll delete this answer in a bit to clean up the database and hopefully avoid confusing future searchers.

Comment: It might be more valuable to explain how tempting a `using` declaration is, and that it won't work according to the Standard, rather than deletion.

Comment: @BenVoigt Done.  Feel free to edit any part of this answer if you feel further clarification is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Just use virtual inheritance, so that the `A` subobject provided by `B` is the same object used in `C`.

Or write `class C : public B`... it will be implicitly usable as an `A` anyway, via the base class `B`.

---

Before the question was edited:

`B::foo` is not compatible with `A::foo`.

The required signature is

```
ReturnType /* missing from question */ foo(A* const this /* this parameter is implicit */);
```

But `B::foo` has the signature

```
ReturnType foo(B* const this);
```

An `A*`, which will be passed to the virtual function, is not a `B*`, which the implementation requires.  If `B` inherited from `A`, then the compiler would generate `B::foo` to accept an `A* const subobject` and find the `B* const this` object from that subobject pointer.  But `B::foo` has no knowledge of the relationship in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the two base classes in your example (which might be a design issue/design smell, I'd review that) you have to explicitly call the implementation that you are after, be it `A::foo()` or `B:foo()`.

If all B does is to provide the implementation of `foo()` I'd consider moving the implementation into A (you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function) but even in this case you'd have to call it via its qualified name.