# virtual keyword in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

In this code when an object of DR is created, the string  "Hello World" should be printed 4 times, instead it is printed just 3 times.**Why is it so** ?
From what I guess it is because of the mid1 and mid2 being virtually inherited.
**Can somebody explain me what happens when we virtually inherit a class and more importantly when it is useful and why ?**

```
#include <iostream>

struct BS
{
  BS()
  {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  }
  unsigned int color;
};

struct mid1 : virtual public BS { };
struct mid2 : virtual public BS { };
struct mid3 : public BS { };
struct mid4 : public BS { };

struct DR : public mid1, public mid2, 
            public mid3, public mid4 { };

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  DR d;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [Take your pick.](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+inheritance)

Comment: Did you mean ""Hello World" should be printed 3 times, and so it is."?

Comment: No from whatever limited knowledge I have it calculated it as 4. But it is printing 3.I want to know the reason.

Comment: For the record, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class#21607) explains it pretty well.

Comment: @K-ballo: I know as the compiler gives it so. I want to know the reason.

Comment: @jairaj, It should be a lot easier to properly count them after reading that answer.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I _think_ if you rearrange `DR`s parents, the answer _might_ change to two.

Comment: I voted down. As showned by chris, you didn't do any Googling here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified example:

```
class base {};

class mid1 : public base {};
class mid2 : public base {};

class derived1 : public mid1, public mid2;

class mid1a : virtual public base {};
class mid2a : virtual public base {};

class derived2 : public mid1a, public mid2a {};
```

If we draw object diagrams for these, we get something like this:

[image]

When the intermediate classes use virtual inheritance, the derived class contains only a single instance of the base class, instead of a separate instance from each intermediate class.

In your case, that leads to three instances of the base class instead of four.