# Is there Virtual class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have read about virtual methods in C#. Is there any concept called virtual class in C#? Is abstract class in C# and virtual class in C++ the same?

Comment: What do you mean by a virtual class in C++?  Do you mean virtual inherentance or a class with a pure virtual function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such thing in C# - and it's really not necessary since multiple implementation inheritance is not supported. Making a class abstract really only means that you cannot create instances of that class and they might not be fully implemented (e.g. might contain abstract methods).

Answer (score 7):

There are no virtual classes in C#. Abstract class is not the same since you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

You can do the opposite of marking something virtual by marking it [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which prevents it from being inherited.

Answer (score 3):

I will opine with a link to this earlier SO post: [In C++ what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

As others have mentioned, since C# does not have multiple inheritance, the need to have a "virtual base class" that limits multiple inheritance is not needed, hence it does not apply to C#. Only members in C# can be virtual.