# Virtual Base Class in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a query regarding the virtual base class. In order to resolve the "dreaded diamond of death" /ambiguity problem in multiple inheritance, virtual base class is introduced.

```
class A { public: void Foo() {} };
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

What will happen when a keyword `virtual` is not used in `class C` declaration. Could you please explain me in detail?

```
class A { public: void Foo() {} };
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Comment: sidenote: do use composition over inheritence (use the component based design pattern)

Comment: "diamond of death" is a problem in C++ multiple inheritance, not in multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

If your inheritance is not `virtual` then `A` members will be present twice in `D` class.

If `A` had a field named `_a`, then, in `D`, writing `B::_a` or `C::_a` would refer to two different memory zones. If your inheritance is `virtual` then you have only one memory zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **virtual** than there will be no ambiguity when you call `foo()` using the instance of `Class D`. and if you are not using virtual than it will be ambiguity..
But be careful that virtual inheritance cost more so use it carefully..

Answer (score 0):

```
class A { public: void Foo() {} };
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

If the inheritance from the A class to B marked virtual but not A class to C, then C++ will create a single virtual A (D inherits B, B inherits A) and a nonvirtual A (D inherits C, C inherits A). Therefore, your code will not solve the diamond problem:

```
D d_object;
A &a_ref = d_object; // error raised -> B::A or C::A
```