# Why is sizeof Derived Class is 8?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Empty
{};


class Derived : virtual public Empty
{
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(Empty) " << sizeof(Empty) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived) " << sizeof(Derived) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Why size is coming 8 I think it should be 9, 
If I declare 'c' as integer then also its coming 8
Cany you please explain me the logic

Comment: Four bytes for the vtable, one byte for the char, three bytes of padding. Why do you think it should be nine?

Comment: You're probably on a 32-bit platform, so the vptr hidden inside your class will be 4 bytes.

Comment: It's the first time I see `virtual` specified up in the inheritance list. Is this syntax legal? Is it better/safer than not specifying `virtual`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes it is legal.  Whether it is better/safer than not specifying it depends on whether you need the virtual base class or not.  (See: [What is a Virtual Base Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size is **Implementation dependent** and it depends on how the particular compiler implementation implements virtualism & padding. You shouldn't expect the value specifically to be something. If you want to calculate the size in your program just use `sizeof` and thats about it.

Answer (score 3):

The size is dependent on implementation. **Four bytes** will be taken for the `vtable`, **one byte** is taken for the `char`, **three bytes** is for `padding`. That makes it **8 bytes**. So it depends how your compiler is implementing the virtualism and padding. You can use sizeof if you want to calculate the size of your program

Comment: Not sure whether a vtable is needed here, or used. Virtual base class offsets can also be stored directly, and could also amount to 4 bytes.

Comment: @MSalters:- Yes you are correct. But I think the first line of the answer is more important that it is dependent on implementation. Although I accept your point +1

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:- SO will it be correct to say that  **Four bytes** will be taken for the object which contains `vptr`?