# Blocking virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, virtual-inheritance

Is there a way in modern C++ to prevent a class from being virtually inherited, while allowing regular inheritance at the same time? Right now it seems impossible to me, but there were too many things in this language that seemed impossible.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your question, but can't you just avoid the "virtual" word?

Comment: Explicitely have no virtual class destructor declaration/definition! And may be even make it `protected`.

Comment: In my case I utterly need a virtual destructor in my class and I need to prevent it from being a virtual base class. Final keyword or private/protected constructor blocks the inheritance totally and that's not what I want

Comment: OP wants to prohibit `struct C : virtual Base {};`

Comment: @VictorK What do you want then, that all sounds a bit contradictorily for me! Elaborate please why you _'In my case I utterly need a virtual destructor'_!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: Normally I'd ask why you want to do this, cause this smells like an X-Y problem. But in this case I'm really curious to know if this is possible.

Comment: @Praetorian Apparently it's not possible, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of the `virtual` keyword specified for an inherited base is to prevent it to occur instantiated multiple times in an inheritance hierarchy. So usage of this can't prevented in first place (see also ['What is a virtual base class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)).
I believe you may have confused what are your possibilities how to control what actually can be overidden by inheriting classes.

If you have no `virtual` methods declared in your class an inheriting class can't provide any `virtual` overrides for any methods from that base.
Best to state this semantically in first place is

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
protected:
    ~Foo() {} // Explicitly non virtual destructor, prevents virtual inheritance
              // 'protected' forces inheritance to use this class
};
```

Even using introduced pure abstract interfaces this should work well

```
struct IFace {
     virtual void some_operation() = 0;
     virtual ~IFace() {}
}; 

class Foo : public IFace {
public:
     // Implementation of interface methods
     virtual void some_operation() { 
     }

    // Same as above. Possibility of virtual inheritance stops here
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Seems that [@DieterLücking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249683/dieter-l%C3%BCcking)'s comment and your online code sample disprove what I said. That obviously doesn't stop from using the `virtual` keyword for inheritance in 1st place, and it seems there's nothing you can do against it.

Though you can prevent inheriting classes to (re-)implement interfaces simply by providing these implementations as private then:

```
class Foo : public IFace {
private:
     // Implementation of interface methods
     virtual void some_operation() { 
     }
};
```

Comment: If you have no virtual methods declared in your class it can't be inherited virtual - that's really something new

Comment: This is wrong, a base class can not make a promise not being inherited virtual.

Comment: @DieterLücking But can make `virtual` inheritance useless, no?!?

Comment: @VictorK See my updates in the answer please! Seems you can't prevent an inheriting class specifying the `virtual` keyword at all, seems you've been confusing purpose of it may be ...

Comment: Virtual inheritance has nothing to do with virtual functions. Man, thank you for your time, but your answer is of no use unfortunately.

Comment: @VictorK I'm with praetorian's comment: _Smells like a xy-problem_. You should clarify in your question what you want to achieve finally. May be it's possible to show you a viable solution then.