# Virtual function ambiguity solving

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

So here I got a descent explanation that what actually is a *virtual function* and why do we really need it,

> **[In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)**

But there still remains a question in my mind that how compiler actually interpret that which definition should be used in case of multiple or hybrid inheritance. For example consider this example

```
class Up {
 public: 
 void func(){
      ...
    } 
};

class Middle_1 : public virtual Up {
 public:
 ...
};

class Middle_2 : public virtual Up {
 public:
 ...
};

class Down : public Middle_1, public Middle_2 {
 public:
 ...
};
```

In above example code, class `Down` is receiving two definition of class `Up` (i.e one from `Middle_1` and another from `Middle_2`). However we had ensured to use the `virtual` tag in `Middle_1` and `Middle_2` class which will remove the case of ambiguity (because compiler will take only one definition) and that is where my question arises.

Actually I am having a bunch of questions,

- **How will compiler select the best suited class?**
- **Will the selection be similar in all conditions?**
- **Didn't it contradict the fact that compiler have zero IQ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The structure of the class `Down` in memory is as follows: {Up}{Middle_1}{Middle_2}{Down}.  The compiler must inherit from both classes, so there isn't a "best suited class" (I think there is some confusion here).  The selection is generally based on the order in which you specify inheritance, but this is probably implementation defined.  Compiler IQ?

Comment: Compilers have zero IQ. The people who write them, usually have very high IQs.

Comment: @Aggieboy: The exact structure layout of `Down` is implementation-defined; the C++ standard doesn't mandate how virtual base classes are to be implemented.  I'm not sure if I've seen that particular layout used for virtual inheritance by compilers, but I've definitely seen the layout `{{P}Middle_1}{{P}Middle_2}{Down}{Up}`, where the `{P}`'s are pointers to the `Up` virtual base class instance.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I believe it DOES have to be in contiguous memory (placement new wouldn't work otherwise), even if the orderings and such are implementation defined.  I was mostly speaking for what `g++` does, but I will check it a bit.

Comment: I am just a starter in C++ and just was trapped in this doubt. I really don't know that whether this one is really silly question but honestly this was my genuine curiosity. And Thank You for reopening my question! It's very kind that someone really tried to understand my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one `Up` *class* in the entire program. No need to select anything.

Perhaps you wanted to ask *how will compiler select the best suited `Up` **subobject**?* Ostensibly there's an `Up` subobject in each `Middle_1` object, and an `Up` subobject in each `Middle_2` subobject. The compiler will need to select one of them to use with `Down`, right?

Wrong. With virtual inheritance, subobjects are not fixed in place relatively to their owners. Neither `Middle_1` nor `Middle_2` create their own `Up` subobjects, and they do not know in advance where these `Up` subobjects live. They only know they are going to have one. *Somebody* will have to hand them down an instance of `Up`.

So the compiler will do a little dirty trick. It will create a *single* `Up` subobject for each `Down` object, and then tell the `Middle_1` part *and* the `Middle_2` part *and* the `Down` part that it is *their* `Up` subobject. So all three parts will treat that single `Up` as their own, completely oblivious to the fact that it is in fact shared.

This scheme did require some non-trivial IQ to *invent*, but every dumb compiler out there is capable of *implementing* it.

Comment: That was really helpful and rather surprising for me too. I never knew that compiler perform such kind of operations also. Thank You very much for providing such a great answer.