# Ill-formed static-cast interpretation

Tags: c++, static-cast

I've come across with the follwing code (sec. 5.4/4 N3797):

```
struct A { };
struct I1 : A { };
struct I2 : A { };
struct D : I1, I2 { };
A* foo( D* p ) {
    return (A*)( p ); // ill-formed static_cast interpretation
}
```

I have been trying to understand the example, but I can't. I haven't used `static_cast` in the example at all. How does it relate to `static_cast`. In general, would you explain the point of the error.

Comment: `A` isn't a virtual base. I.e. there is no diamond pattern here. Thus there are *two* `A`'s laid out in a `D`. So which `A` do you expect the result of `foo()` to be addressing, the one `I1` derives from, or the one `I2` derives from? The ambiguity is the reason for the error.

Comment: Check out Virtual Inheritance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

Comment: @WhozCraig What's the diamond pattern?

Comment: @St.Antario there *isn't one*. That's the point. If there were *one* "instance" of `A` "shared" as the base of *both* `I1` and `I2` you would have one. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class/112474#112474). (and looking back at your comment, I see you asked "What", not "Where". Sorry for the confusion. Hope that linked answer helps (it should).

Comment: @WhozCraig At what is the static_cast?

Comment: "I haven't used static_cast in the example at all". Too bad, because you should, in preference of the old C-style casts.

Comment: @St.Antario jxh just saved me the time of pasting the standard citation. See that answer. its an order-of-application thing.

Comment: @n.m. Why? What's bad in C-style casts?

Comment: [This is too broad for a comment](https://www.google.com/search?q=C-style+casts+are+bad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "C style cast" is called "explicit type conversion", and is discussed in §5.4 if the C.11 standard. In ¶4:

> The conversions performed by
>   — a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
>   — a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
>   — a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>   — a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10), or
>   — a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>   can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.

Which is basically saying a `static_cast` may be the result of a cast expression. It then lists some conditions under which it is a valid `static_cast`, and the example you cite was an example when it was invalid. Just before that example was the following text (the very end of ¶4):

> If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed. If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one way as a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, the conversion is ill-formed.

The reason the example listed is ill-formed is because both `I1` and `I2` do non-`virtual` inheritance from `A`. Thus, `D`, which uses multiple inheritance on `I1` and `I2` will have two `A` instances within it, and so trying to cast a `D *` to an `A *` has more than one interpretation. The programmer needs to specify which `A *` instance should result to avoid an ill-formed conversion.

ASCII art alert:

```
+---+          +---+
| A |          | A |
+---+          +---+
  |              |
 /_\            /_\
  |              |
+----+         +----+
| I1 |         | I2 |
+----+         +----+
  |              |
  +------.-------+
         |
        /_\
         |
       +---+
       | D |
       +---+
```

Comment: +1 for the citation. The OP should note the term *"explicit type conversion"*, which denotes the application of `(T)`; in this case `T` is `A*`.

Comment: How to determine how many ways to interpret an appropriate cast-expression?

Comment: The conversions are applied in the order above, and the first one that can be used is the one used, even if it is ill-formed. The reason for ill-formed is not that more than one applies, but that the choice for `A *` is ambiguous.

Comment: "*The programmer needs to specify which `A *` instance should result to avoid an ill-formed conversion.*" Do you mean something like this `return (D::I1::A*)(p)` ? If so, the cast is still ill-formed!

Comment: @cpper I didn't specify how to do that. You should be able to cast to `I1 *` or `I2 *` first, and then convert that pointer to `A *`.