# Why is the size of a class with only a char 8 if it inherits virtually?

Tags: c++

I have this

```
class Empty {};  // Empty class

class Derived : virtual public Empty
{
        char c;
};
```

On my machine, `sizeof(Derived);` is `8`, why? Isn't it supposed to be `1` because it only has 1 `char` in it?

When I remove the virtual inheritance, `sizeof(Derived);` is `1`.

Comment: Uh the compiler does it. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: What's the result and what do you expect and why? At least show some effort solving that question yourself!

Comment: did you read any [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)? What is it that is unclear?

Comment: You might want to read up on exactly what [virtual inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class) is and how it works. Virtual inheritance requires some extra book keeping, which is why it results in a larger object size.

Comment: ...and if you're on a 64bit machine, it becomes 16, same reason: pointer and padding.

Comment: You might want to read up on *alignment* and *structure padding*.  On some platforms, the compiler pads to 8-byte boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

> On my machine, `sizeof(Derived);` is 8, why?

Because that's what the compiler chose. The representation of the object may need more memory due to the virtual base. In a typical implementation, there will be a "virtual table pointer" within the object.

> Isn't it supposed to be 1 because it only has 1 char in it?

No. The size of an object is not "*supposed to be*" the sum of the size of it's members.