# Share variables with classes multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I'm trying to design class hierarchy for my physical simulations. I really want to share variables (e.g. `Vec3d pos`, `Quat4d rot` ) between classes which depend on each other by more complex graph of multiple-inheritance. I extracted simple example what is the problem (full code is [here](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/cppEngineConcept/engine/Bodies.h)):

```
// ==== prefabricates for classes ... I was thinking this will solve the problem
class _pos { public: Vec3d pos;};
class _rot { public: Quat4d rot;};

// === classes 

class KinematicBody : public _pos, public _rot{
    // pos, rot   ... inherited
    void toGLmat( float * mat ); // make Opengl 4x4 matrix for rendering
};

class PointBody : public _pos, public Updateable {
    public:
    // pos    ...  inherited
    Vec3d   vel,force;
    double  mass;

    inline  void update_(double dt){ vel.add_mul(force, dt); pos.add_mul(vel,(dt/mass)); };  // can be called as obj->PointBody::update_(dt);
    virtual void update (double t, double dt ){ update_(dt); }; // implements Updateable
};

// !!!! HERE IS THE PROBLEM
class RigidBody : public PointBody, public KinematicBody {  // WARRNING : both PointBody and KinematicBody inheriate "pos"
   public:
   // pos,vel,force,mass,rot    ...  inherited
   Mat3d  momentOfInertia;
   Vec3d  torque;
   Vec3d  angular_velocity;
};
```

I tried to run following test to make sure that  `KinematicBody::pos`, `PointBody::pos`, `RigidBody::pos` all share the same piece of memory (full code [here](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/cppEngineConcept/tests/test_Basics.cpp)):

```
RigidBody        rb;
KinematicBody  * kb = &rb;
PointBody      * pb = &rb;

rb. pos.set(1.0); printf( "%f %f %f\n", rb.pos.x, kb->pos.x, pb->pos.x );
kb->pos.set(2.0); printf( "%f %f %f\n", rb.pos.x, kb->pos.x, pb->pos.x );
pb->pos.set(3.0); printf( "%f %f %f\n", rb.pos.x, kb->pos.x, pb->pos.x );
```

I expected result like

```
1.0000   1.0000   1.0000
2.0000   2.0000   2.0000
3.0000   3.0000   3.0000
```

But instead I got following error:

```
error: request for member ‘pos’ is ambiguous  
rb. pos.set(1.0); printf( "%f %f %f\n", rb.pos.x, kb->pos.x, pb->pos.x );
```

This error can be probably resolved by making

`class RigidBody : public PointBody, public _rot {`

instead of

`class RigidBody : public PointBody, public KinematicBody {`

but than I cannot inherit `void toGLmat( float * mat );` from `KinematicBody`
... and in general it makes composition of classes very unconveneient

Is there any way how to achieve this sharing? I was thinking that by making *prefabricates* like `_pos` and `_rot` I can achieve this, but apparently not.

Comment: Have you considered using `public virtual _pos, public virtual _rot`? There are multiple SO questions and answers regarding the _diamond problem_ in C++.

Comment: You should read about the difference between an "is a" and a "has a" relationship. Public inheritance means "is a", but a `KinematicBody` is not a position or a rotation, it just "has a" position and rotation. "has a" is expressed via members. Once you apply that throughout your code it will become much clearer and easier to use.

Comment: @Torbjörn `virtual` should be applied here: `class RigidBody : public PointBody, public KinematicBody { ...` This is where th _diamond_ is introduced.

Comment: @Torbjörn thanks,  I resolved the issue by this modification:
`class KinematicBody : public virtual _pos, public _rot{`  and `class PointBody : public virtual _pos, public Updateable {` but I don't really know what `virtual` means in this context (I know only virtual functions) and if there is any performance or memory overhead (is the memory really shared)?

Comment: @ProkopHapala Read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class

Comment: @ProkopHapala Inheritance is a major design flaw in your example.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ thanks, I read it before, but it is mostly about functions  (almost everything I read about diamond problem is about functions), but it does not answer the question of overhead. So I did some performance tests now ... acesss to `_pos::pos.x` costs 3-4 CPU ticks, `RigidBody::pos.x` costs 35 ticks without virtual inheritance and 44 ticks with virtual inheritance (I guess the biggest issue is memory latency since sizeof(RigidBody) = 240 bytes ) ... all tested by 100 traversing array of 1000000 items. So the slow-down is perhaps not so critical for large object like this.

Comment: anyway I do not understand why there must be some performance overhead :-(   . I would think that deduction of memory address of `pos` can be fully determined in compile time whether it is shared (virtual) or not.

Comment: There's a performance overhead because `RigidBody` requires the ability to share a single base `_pos` between `KinematicBody` and `PointBody`, instead of them both having separate `_pos`es.  Therefore, one or both of the classes must refer to this `_pos` by pointer/reference, which imposes a dereferencing cost.  As this `_pos` must be valid before either `KineticBody` or `PointBody` are constructed, both classes will store a ptr/ref to it so that the compiler can more easily have the most-derived class (in this case, `RigidBody`) construct it.  Therefore, each access requires a dereference.

Comment: That said, I don't believe your inheritance hierarchy is set up properly.  Neither body is a position or a rotation; instead, one is a body with a position, and one is a body with a position and a rotation.  Therefore, I would suggest `class Body { public: Vec3d pos; };` as the base "body" class, and `class RotatableBody : public virtual Body { public: Quat4d rot; };` as the "rotatable body" class.  This lets `KinematicBody` inherit from `RotatableBody` and `PointBody` virtually inherit from `Body`, [as so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/191b02eddd52ed3c).

Comment: @Justine: ad 2 - How I call those classes does (`_pos`) not matter, I don't want to use them anywhere (that is why I call them *prefabricates* and why I put `_` in front). The only reason why they exist is that I wanted to use them as components from which I can assemble real classes by multiple inheritance. Purpose of `class _pos` is just to add `Vec3d pos` into whatever inheriate from it ... so the name is suitable

Comment: @Justine: ad 2 runtime cost - I still don't see why any pointer/reference and dereferencing is needed. For compiler `RigidBody::pos` means nothing else than memory location at [address of some RigidBody instance]+[offset of pos]. Without `virtual` there are two different offsets for `KineticBody::pos` and `PointBody::pos`, but I don't see why compiler cannot just translate this `virtual` inheritance such that it makes both offsets the same. It is like with templates - all is static and can be fully determined in compile time. Virtual functions with `vtable` is completely different thing.