# Inheritance in C++, "...is an ambiguous base of ..." error

Tags: c++

As written in "The C++ Programming Language 3.Edition - Bjarne Stroustrup". We can use scope solution to prevent ambiguity errors. The basic program which is in below, when i use 3 layer scope in class mix an error occurs. But when i use 2 layer no problem. What is wrong? or is it something like design issue? The error is;

```
deneme.cpp: In constructor ‘mix::mix(std::__cxx11::string, int)’:
deneme.cpp:45:22: error: ‘plane’ is an ambiguous base of ‘mix’
    pervaneli::plane::engine=b;
```

I don't want to make a diamond model. I am happy with two base (plane) classes. The thing that i just want to learn why it gives error when i use 3 layer scope. Thanks.

Note: Version is g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class plane{
    protected:
    int speed;
    string name;
    public:
        int engine;
        void its_name(){
            cout<<name<<endl;
        }
        plane(int a=10000){
            engine=a;
        }

};

class pervaneli:public plane{
    public:
        pervaneli(string a="-"){
            name=a;
        }
        void belirle(int x){
            speed=x;
        }
};

class jet:public plane{
    public:
        jet(string a="-"){
            name=a;
        }
        void belirle(int x){
            speed=x;
        }
};

class mix: public pervaneli,public jet{
    public:
        mix(string a,int b){
            jet::name=a;
            pervaneli::name=a;
            pervaneli::plane::engine=b; //ambigous base error
            //pervaneli::engine=b; /*works fine*/
        } 
        void belirle(int x){
            jet::speed=x;
        }
};


int main()
    {
    mix a400m("Alp",9999);
    a400m.belirle(500);
    a400m.pervaneli::its_name();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe dupe (it answers your problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class

Comment: It is not about virtual. I don't want to make a diamond model.

Comment: Yes, it is. Your code suffers from the Diamond problem, which can be solved using virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I Don't want to make Diamond. I exactly want two plane base classes. The problem is why does it give error when i use 3 layer scope.

Comment: Whether it is your intention or not, the compiler will recognize it as a diamond pattern with an ambiguous call as result. The answer of Rakete1111 with virtual is the way to go.

Comment: I think `pervaneli::plane::engine` is `typename` `pervaneli::plane` `::engine`. So `plane::engine` which is ambiguous.

Comment: @GillBates: OP has and wants Y inheritance, not a diamond (with virtual inheritance).

Comment: The question is more interesting than critiquing OP for the diamond, i.e. why doesn't pervaneli::plane identify the correct base instance when pervanelli does.

Comment: I don't want to make this functionless (i mean stupid) code to work :) when i use 2 layers scope it works properly. I just want to learn why do i get error when use 3 layers scope. Please, don't suggest me to use virtual or any other.

Comment: Changing non-virtual to virtual inheritance is a **design** change; a design change is **never**, in itself, an appropriate solution to a **coding** problem. A coding problem can point to a possible design flaw, but, as the OP keep saying, in this case the design is correct.

Comment: @Pete Yes, you are right. I noticed it too after giving it some thought :) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [qualified_lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup)

`pervaneli::plane` is the injected-class-name `plane` (the type).

so `pervaneli::plane::engine` is in fact `plane::engine`, which is ambiguous as you have two base class `plane`.

You cannot give full path to the member you want.

Comment: Yes, it's the type NOT the subobject, and note the difference between `this->pervaneli::plane::engine` and `static_cast<pervaneli*>(this)->plane::engine`

Answer (score 1):

Public inheritance means `is a` relationship.
 *Reference: Effective C++: Item 32: Make sure public inheritance models “is-a.”*

So `pervaneli` is a `plane` because of public inheritance. The class `pervaneli` already has the member variable `engine` in it because of `is a` relationship with `plane`.

By adding the scope of `plane` you are making it ambiguous for the compiler hence the error.