# Upcasting to a C++ class that is a base class in more than one way (without having to use virtual inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
class A { };
class B : public  A {};
class C : public A, public B {};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pA = static_cast<A *>(&c);
}
```

In the above code, class C is derived from class A in two different paths:
1. Directly from A
2. Indirectly through B i.e. A<-B<-C

So, when I cast an object of class C into a pointer to class A, g++ on Linux reports the following error:
 error: A is an ambiguous base of C

I have also tried the same code by removing the static cast as follows:
    A *pA = &c;
But, I still get exactly the same error.

Is there any solution for this? BTW, the same works fine without error on Windows using Visual C++ compiler.

I know that virtual inheritance solves this but I need a solution to make this work on g++ on Linux without having to use virtual inheritance. Rather than having to use virtual inheritance, is there any way I can instead specify one of the two path and get rid of the ambiguity. Many thanks!

Comment: First, your inheritance tree is a code smell. Second, what you are looking for is virtual inheritance. Look that up ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you need two separate inherited instances of `A` in your `C`? Is composition an option?

Comment: @YSC -- no, changing the **design** is not a solution to a **coding** problem. It's not unreasonable to have **two** bases of the same type, and it's not unreasonable to ask how to manage them.

Comment: Re: "I know that virtual inheritance solves this" -- not really. If you need two instances of the base class, changing to virtual inheritance eliminates the **coding** problem but also eliminates the two bases that were part of the original design.

Comment: @PeteBecker who suggested a change in design? I surely did not!

Comment: @YSC - "what you are looking for is virtual inheritance" suggests a design change, going from **two** copies of `A` to **one** copy of `A`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ho that, yes you're right. Read a bit too quick.

Answer (score 5):

If you can modify `C`, one possible approach would be to "inject" a dummy base class between it and `A`:

```
class A { };
class B : public  A {};
class AlmostA : public A {};
class C : public AlmostA, public B {};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pA = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<AlmostA*>(&c));
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ed4be135b5db265)

You can even embed the dual static casts into a function in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, inherit from `A` *virtually* to avoid having two distinct `A`s being a part of `C`:

```
class A { };
class B : virtual public A {};
class C : virtual public A, public B {};
```

Now your code will compile and run correctly.

Unlike "regular" base classes, virtual base classes are inherited only once, regardless of the number of paths that have them. Read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21558/335858) for a detailed explanation of how they work.

Comment: I had assumed the OP actually needed two separate `A` instances due to the way the question was formulated.

Comment: @MarkB Given that there are no members in any of OP's classes, it is hard to tell if his intention was to have one or two `A`s in a `C`. To me it is highly unusual to want to have two `A`s, so I made an assumption that OP wants a single one.