# C++ size of virtual inheritance classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual, sizeof

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
    int mem1;
    float mem2;
};
class MyKids: public virtual MyClass{
    int cmem1;
    int cmem2;
};
class MyLawKids:public virtual MyClass{
    int lmem1;
};
class MyGrands:public MyKids, public MyLawKids{
    int gmem1;
};

int main(){
    cout << "\n Size of MyClass: " << sizeof(MyClass) << " bytes" << endl ;
    cout << " Size of MyKids: " << sizeof(MyKids) << " bytes" << endl ;
    cout << " Size of MyLawKids: " << sizeof(MyLawKids) << " bytes" << endl ;
    cout << " Size of MyGrands: " << sizeof(MyGrands) << " bytes" << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
 Size of MyClass: 8 bytes
 Size of MyKids: 20 bytes
 Size of MyLawKids: 16 bytes
 Size of MyGrands: 32 bytes

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.094 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I think the size of MyGrands class its should be 36 bytes = (sizeof(MyKids + MyLawKids + int gmem1) - 4 bytes of virtual table pointer).

Why my result shown me "Size of MyGrands: 32 bytes" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member (padding is involved, different compiler or platform may result in different results)

Comment: Virtual inheritance, multiple inheritance you could (probably) do without.

Comment: btw the difference in size you observe is just a consequence of what virtual inheritance is made for. Any article on virtual inheritance should contain an explanation of the effect you see

Answer (score 2):

`MyGrands` contains only one instance of `MyClass` due to `MyKids` and `MyLawKids` [inheriting virtually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class) from `MyClass`. Hence your calculation is wrong, by double counting the size of `MyClass`. By the way, in general you should not rely on a naive addition of the pieces being the same as the size of the whole. The compiler can add padding.