# How to delegate to implementing class

Tags: c++

I have an abstract base class `Node`, which is derived from an abstract Interface class `IObservable`.
There is a several classes implementing the abstract `IObservable`: `SingleObservable` and `MultiObservable`

I want to create a class `ObservableNode`, derived from the base `Node` class and specify on its declaration which class to use for the implementation of the `IObservable` interface.

I've added `using ...` statements for every pure virtual method in `IObservable`, referring to the methods in the implementation classes but I still get errors saying that `ObservableNode` is an abstract class, missing the implementation of `notifyObservers(IObject*)`.

If I add the parameter `IObject*` to the `using` statement I get an "expected ';' before '(' token" error

How can I solve this?

```
class IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~IObservable() {};
    virtual void notifyObservers(IObject*) = 0;
};
class SingleObservable: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~SingleObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
      //some implementaiton
    };
};
class MultiObservable: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~MultiObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
      //some other implementaiton
    };
};

class Node: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {};
};

class ObservableNode: public Node, public SingleObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~ObservableNode() {};
    using SingleObservable::notifyObservers;
    // using SingleObservable::notifyObservers(IObject*); // expected ';' before '(' token error

};


Node* node = new ObservableNode() // instantiating abstract class error, missing notifyObservers(IObject*) implementation
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you inherit `Node` which is still abstract, and also causes to introduce the good old [multimple inheritance vicious diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) problem. When I change your code like this, the error disappears:

```
class Node: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {};
    // ** Added an implementation here **
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
          //some other implementaiton
    };
};

class ObservableNode: public virtual Node, public virtual SingleObservable {
                          // ^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^
  public:
    virtual ~ObservableNode() {};
    using SingleObservable::notifyObservers;
};

int main() {
    Node* node = new ObservableNode();
}
```

See it [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0de9753d89e6aca3).

Comment: @Scheff THX adopted it. Not to inherit `Node` from `IObservable` would be certainly an alternative solution. You may still post that as an answer.

Comment: That indeed solved the problem, thanks! And indeed, I do want the IObservable interface in the Node definition

Comment: Note that in this particular example, `Node* node = new ObservableNode();` will mean `node->notifyObservers(obj)` will invoke `Node::notifyObservers(IObject*)` and not `SingleObservable::notifyObservers(IObject*)`, which might be unexpected, considering we instantiate an `ObservableNode` object which specifies `using SingleObservable::notifyObservers;`. What OP might possible want is to, in `ObservableNode`, define an `notifyObservers(IObject*)` override which explictly forwards to `SingleObservable::notifyObservers(IObject*)`.

Comment: @Bascy You should be aware of that previous comment. You're still struggling with the diamond ambiguity  problem, and might get unexpected results.

Comment: ... then a call `node->notifyObservers(obj)` will go down the vtable to `ObservableNode::notifyObservers(IObject*)`, and from there explicitly up to (by forwarding) `SingleObservable::notifyObservers(IObject*)`.

Answer (score 3):

[@πάντα ῥεῖ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890625/4573247) describe one workaround, but possible this is not what OP is after here. Also, as [my comment describe under the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890369/how-to-delegate-to-implementing-class#comment98438244_55890625), the approach in the answer might give unexpected results e.g. when invoking `node->notifyObservers(obj)`:

> Note that in this particular example, `Node* node = new
>   ObservableNode();` will mean `node->notifyObservers(obj)` will invoke
>   `Node::notifyObservers(IObject*)` and not
>   `SingleObservable::notifyObservers(IObject*)`, which might be
>   unexpected, considering we instantiate an `ObservableNode` object
>   which specifies using `SingleObservable::notifyObservers;`.

In OP's original code, we are suffering from multiple inheritance ambiguity, as *we are **not** using `virtual` inheritance* when `Node` and `SingleObservable` (and `MultiObservable`) derives from `IObservable`:

> ```
> class SingleObservable: public IObservable {
>   public:
>     virtual ~SingleObservable() {};
>     void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
>       //some implementaiton
>     };
> };
>
> class Node: public IObservable {
>   public:
>     virtual ~Node() {};
> };
> ```

Meaning our [the object's memory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112474/4573247), w.r.t. inheritance, of `ObservableNode` to looks like the following

```
 IObservable  IObservable
           |  |
        Node  SingleObservable
           \  /
       ObservableNode
```

whereas, in this context, we are likely to want an object's memory layout looking as follows

```
       IObservable
           /  \
        Node  SingleObservable
           \  /
       ObservableNode
```

If we were to correct this, `Node` can stay abstract, and a call to `node->notifyObservers(obj)` with `node` as OP's example will result in invocation of `SingleObservable::notifyObservers`, as might have been expected.

```
class Node: public virtual IObservable {
                // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {};
};

class SingleObservable: public virtual IObservable {
                            // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
  public:
    virtual ~SingleObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
        std::cout << "SingleObservable::notifyObservers";
    };
};

struct DummyObj : public IObject {};

int main() {
    Node* node = new ObservableNode();
    DummyObj obj;
    node->notifyObservers(obj);  // SingleObservable::notifyObservers
}
```

Note that we not need `virtual` inheritance for when `ObservableNode` derives from `Node` and `SingleObservable`.

Finally, *if* we'd want `Node` be non-abstract (specifically, to provide an override of `void notifyObservers(IObject*)`), then `ObservableNode` must provide it's own (`final`) override of it, as we will otherwise inherit two final overrides of it in  `ObservableNode` (one from `Node` and one from `SingleObservable`). In this case, `ObservableNode` could simply define its own override which explicitly calls the base class of choice, e.g.

```
class Node: public virtual IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
        std::cout << "Node::notifyObservers";
    };
};

class SingleObservable: public virtual IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~SingleObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
        std::cout << "SingleObservable::notifyObservers";
    };
};

class ObservableNode: public Node, public SingleObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~ObservableNode() {};
    // Non-ambiguous final override in ObservableNode.
    // We could use `override` specifier here, but we might as well
    // use `final`, if we are not expecting something to derive from ObservableNode.
    void notifyObservers(IObject* obj) final { 
        SingleObservable::notifyObservers(obj);
    };
};

struct DummyObj : public IObject {};

int main() {
    Node* node = new ObservableNode();
    DummyObj obj;
    node->notifyObservers(obj);  // SingleObservable::notifyObservers
}
```

See [ISO C++ FAQ - Inheritance — Multiple and Virtual Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance) for details on the diamond inheritance structure and virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! Implementing those caused a lot of other problems with other classes already using the `Observable` implementations, so I opted to solve it in a different manner, by including an implementation instance and delegating all methods to that one

```
class IObject {
    public:
    virtual ~IObject() {};
};

class IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~IObservable() {};
    virtual void notifyObservers(IObject*) = 0;
};

class SingleObservable: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~SingleObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
        std::cout << "Single\n";
      //some implementaiton
    };
};

class MultiObservable: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~MultiObservable() {};
    void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { 
        std::cout << "Multi\n";
      //some other implementaiton
    };
};

class Node: public IObservable {
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {};
    // void notifyObservers(IObject*) override { };
};

class SingleObservableNode: public Node {
  public:
    SingleObservableNode() {};
    virtual ~SingleObservableNode() {
        delete obs;
    };
    void notifyObservers(IObject* obj) override { 
        obs->notifyObservers(obj);
    }
    private:
     IObservable* obs = new SingleObservable();
};


class MultiObservableNode: public Node {
  public:
    MultiObservableNode() {};
    virtual ~MultiObservableNode() {
        delete obs;
    };
    void notifyObservers(IObject* obj) override { 
        obs->notifyObservers(obj);
    }
    private:
     IObservable* obs = new MultiObservable();
};

Node* node1 = new SingleObservableNode(); 
Node* node2 = new MultiObservableNode(); 

int main()
{
    node1->notifyObservers(nullptr);   // "Single"
    node2->notifyObservers(nullptr);   // "Multi"
   return 0;
}
```