# How to fix "error: no matching function for call to" when inheriting twice from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, initializer-list

I am currently trying to implement a hirachy of inherited classes in my project. Therefore I am using member initializer-lists and "pipe" a reference to a variable all the way down to the base class. I am really not sure, why I am getting a compiler error.

I have already tried to change the reference "int &id" to a pointer "int* id". 
The example below above is just a minimal example that points out my problem:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    int& m_id;

    Base(int &id)
        : m_id(id)
    {
    }
};

class Derived1: virtual public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(int &id) : Base(id)
    {
    };
};

class Derived2: public Derived1
{
public:
    Derived2(int &id) : Derived1(id)
    {
    };
};

int main()
{
   int i = 13;
   Derived2 Test(i);
}
```

I am getting the following error message when trying to compile:

"error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’"

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual inheritance and virtual functions are different concepts.

Virtual inheritance is special in that
virtual bases need to be explicitly initialized by all derived classes.
In this case, `Derived2` tries to delegate the initialization of `Base` to `Derived1`, 
but that's not valid.
What the constructor of `Derived2` actually does is
to call the default constructor of `Base`
because of the omission of a *mem-initializer* that initializes the `Base`.

You should call the constructor of `Base` explicitly:

```
class Derived2 :public Derived1 {
public:
    Derived2(int &id) : Base(id), Derived1(id)
    {
    };
};
```

Of course, if `Derived1` were not to virtually derive from `Base`,
then `Derived1`'s derived classes can just rely on `Derived1`'s constructor
to initialize `Base`.
So another fix, depending on your situation,
is to simply remove the `virtual` in the *base-specifier*:

```
class Derived1 :public Base {
public:
    Derived1(int &id) :Base(id)
    {
    };
};

class Derived2: public Derived1 {
public:
    Derived2(int &id) :Derived1(id)
    {
    };
};
```

Comment: What would be the effect if I removed that virtual? Virtual methods and functions are clear to me. But what is the effect when marking a derived class as "virtual" or as "public virtual"?

Comment: @nilsmelchert I have updated my answer to address your first question. For your second question, you can consult the Stack Overflow question [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21558).

Comment: But `Derived1` also calls the constructor of `Base` in its initializer-list. So I do not quiet unterstand why I would have to explicitly call the constructor of `Base` when creating an instance of `Derived2`.
Is the constructor of `Derived1` simply ignored, when working with virtual base classes?

Comment: @nilsmelchert Yes. A virtual base class is essentially "global" to the entire inheritance system. All derived classes have to deal with virtual base classes explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual inheritance is a strange beast. It requires that the most-derived class initializes the virtual base classes. In your case, that initialization is missing. This should do it:

```
class Derived2: public Derived1
{
public:
    Derived2(int &id) : Base(id), Derived1(id)
    {
    }
};
```