# Compilation error when using multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, multiple-inheritance

Can't get my program compile. For historical reason I have a bit "complicated" hierarchy of the classes in my application. And now I faced with another problem: it won't compile because of this hierarchy. My project is too big to show it here, but below you can see the example that demonstrates the problem. Is there is a simple and elegant way to fix it? Every interface/class has really big amount of methods.
Thanks in advance.

```
struct ITest
{
    virtual ~ITest() {}
    virtual void a() = 0;
    // and many other methods
};

struct Test1 : public ITest
{
    virtual ~Test1() {}
    virtual void a() override {}
    // and many other methods overrides from ITest
    // plus a lot of other logic
};

struct ExtendedTest1 : public Test1
{
    virtual ~ExtendedTest1() {}
    // a lot of some other stuff
};

struct ITest2 : public ITest
{
    virtual ~ITest2(){}
    // and big count of the its methods and logic
};

struct MainClass : public ExtendedTest1, public ITest2
{
     virtual ~MainClass(){}
     // a lot of logic
};

int main()
{
    MainClass mainClassObj;
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:36:15: error: cannot declare variable ‘mainClassObj’ to be of abstract type ‘MainClass’
     MainClass mainClassObj;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:28:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘MainClass’:
 struct MainClass : public ExtendedTest1, public ITest2
        ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:18: note:    virtual void ITest::a()
     virtual void a() = 0;
                  ^
```

Do not judge strictly :)

UPD: before asking this question I really tried virtual inheritance to solve my problem but it didn't work. So after suggestion to try it again, it works) So, replacing these lines solved my problem:

```
struct Test1 : public ITest  --->  struct Test1 : virtual public ITest
struct ITest2 : public ITest ---> struct ITest2 : virtual public ITest
```

I know, we must avoid virtual inheritance, but we can't 'cause of historical reason and very big amount of code

Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: Perhaps you need [virtual iheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)?

Comment: @Chipster, can you please rewrite your comment to answer? I want to mark it as "answer". Indeed, virtual inheritance solved my problem. I actually tried it, but I did it in a wrong way. And after few minutes of the fresh air I did it :)

Comment: I wrote it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Virtual Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Virtual inheritance can get rid of redundant functions:

> Instead, if classes B and C inherit virtually from class A, then objects of class D will contain only one set of the member variables from class A.

If you inherit virtually, you will get rid of your duplicate abstract function.

Answer (score 2):

The function `a` *is* pure virtual, as in it's not implemented anywhere in the hierarchy `MainClass` -> `ITest2` -> `ITest`.

See the "[deadly diamond of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)" problem of multi-inheritance for more discussion.

The easiest solution is to avoid doing this type of inheritance if you're not exactly sure of what you're doing. Second, you may consider implementing `a` in `MainClass` which forwards the arguments to a qualified call to `a` in `Test1` if that's what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

`MainClass` has two base classes, both of which are derived (directly or indirectly) from `ITest`.  So there are two `ITest` subobjects in `MainClass`.  One of these base classes provides an override for `a`, but the other (`ITest2`) does not.  The implementation in `Test1` is not accessible from `ITest2`.  So `MainClass` will need to provide an implementation.

If you want `Test1::a` to be called even from the `ITest2` subobject, you can have `MainClass` redirect those calls to `Test1::a`.

```
struct MainClass: public ExtendedTest1, public ITest2
{
    // ...
    void a() override { ExtendedTest1::a(); }
};
```

Another possibility is [virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class).