# Virtual function being redefined in other base classes

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Consider this code snippet:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Mammal;
class Operation;

class Animal{
    public:
        virtual void doOp(Operation* op) = 0;
};

class Mammal{
    public:
        void doOp(Operation* op){
            op->thisIsMammal(this);
        }
};

class Pig:  public Mammal, public Animal{

};

class Operation{
    public: 
        void thisIsMammal(Mammal* mammal){
            cout << "This is a mammal!" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Pig  pig;
    Operation op;
    pig.doOp(&op);
    return 0;
}
```

There is a virtual function declared in `Animal` class that needs to be redefined in `Pig` class. However, `Pig` derives from Mammal which has the definition of this function

I still get an error that the function has not been redefined in the derived class. Is there any way to make the definition in `Mammal` sufficient?

Comment: No, C++ does not work this way. You have to declare the virtual function in the subclass, and have the subclass's function explicitly call the implementation in the implementing superclass.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58208774/10957435) is what's going on?

Comment: You may also want to research/use the [override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Answer (score 2):

> However, Pig derives from Mammal which has the definition of this function

No, it doesn't. `Mammal` does not override the function `Animal::doOp` because `Mammal` does not inherit `Animal`.

A simple solution is to derive `Mammal` from `Animal`, and remove the `Animal` base from `Pig`:

```
class Mammal : public Animal {

class Pig :  public Mammal {
```

Comment: See, and I was going to suggest virtual inheritance. I like this better.

Comment: @Chipster virtual inheritance is a *very sharp* tool that should almost *never* be used, and *if* used, it should only be done by experts who *really* know what they are doing (IMHO).

Comment: @JesperJuhl What is the most significant hazard w/ virtual inheritance?

Comment: It is very difficult to decide what is worse - multiple inheritance as in the question, or multiple inheritance as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Mammal` in your code does not derive from `Animal`, so it can't really override the virtual function `Animal::doOp()`. The definition of the member function `Mammal::doOp()` in your code just defines a non-`virtual` function named `doOp()`. It overrides nothing.

#### Consider using the `override` specifier (since C++11).

If you had used the [`override` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) when you thought you were overriding `doOp()` in `Mammal`, you would have got a compilation error at this stage since the following member function definition does not override `doOp()`:

```
class Mammal{
    public:
        void doOp(Operation* op) override {
            op->thisIsMammal(this);
        }
};
```