# Alternative to virtual inheritance in re-using base template implementation

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

In a project I'm working on we're using a pattern where we have pure abstract classes defining an interface, and template implementations that may be instantiated with different template parameters, which are used for many things, including dependency injection. Something like:

```
struct Base {
  virtual int getVal() = 0;
};

template <typename DI>
struct BaseImpl : public Base {
  int getVal() override { return DI::k_Val; }
};
```

I guess question zero is whether this is a known/common/formal pattern, and if so, what's its name?

A need that commonly arises is to extend the `Base` interface, say to `Inherited`. Any `Inherited` object should still polymorphically function as a `Base`, but also as `Inherited`, which may define additional methods. Something like:

```
struct Inherited : public Base {
  virtual int getOtherVal() = 0;
};
```

The problem lies in re-using the implementation of `BaseImpl<>` in `InheritedImpl<>`. Because `InheritedImpl<>` would need to inherit from `Inherited` and `BaseImpl<>` we run into the ["dreaded dimond"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607/5090527) problem, so we have to use virtual inheritance. See working example in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bshE4598z).

```
struct Base {
  virtual int getVal() = 0;
};

template <typename DI>
struct BaseImpl : public virtual Base {
  int getVal() override { return DI::k_Val; }
};

struct Inherited : public virtual Base {
  virtual int getOtherVal() = 0;
};

template <typename DI>
struct InheritedImpl : public Inherited, public BaseImpl<DI> {
  int getOtherVal() override { return DI::k_OtherVal; }
};

void useBase(Base& base) {
    std::cout << "getVal: " << base.getVal() << std::endl;
}

void useInherited(Inherited& inherited) {
    std::cout << "getOtherVal: " << inherited.getOtherVal() << std::endl;
}

struct DI {
  static constexpr int k_Val = 1;
  static constexpr int k_OtherVal = 2;
};

int main() {
  auto base = std::make_unique<BaseImpl<DI>>();
  auto inherited = std::make_unique<InheritedImpl<DI>>();

  useBase(*base);
  useBase(*inherited);
  useInherited(*inherited);
}
```

> ```
> getVal: 1
> getVal: 1
> getOtherVal: 2
> ```

Because of the [issues with virtual inheritance](https://hownot2code.com/2016/08/12/good-and-bad-sides-of-virtual-inheritance-in-c/) I'd like to avoid using it here, if possible. Are there any alternatives in this case? Is this potentially a code smell? Any architectural advice?

Comment: One possible trick: `template <typename DI, typename BaseClass = Base> struct BaseImpl : public BaseClass {...};` Now `InheritedImpl<>` can derive from `BaseImpl<Inherited>` giving you a straight-line inheritance chain: `Base` -> `Inherited` -> `BaseImpl` -> `InheritedImpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pattern is:

```
struct Base{
  virtual int count()const=0;
};
template<class X, class B=Base>
struct CountImpl:B{
   int count()const final{ return X::count; }
};
```

now we can `CountImpl<Foo, Extended>` to rebase the inheritance.

Fancier stuff, with plug in aspects etc, can be done.  In simpler cases this is not worth it, and complex cases that do need it should be avoided.