# How to make 2 base classes to use the same property of their base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int a;

    Base() : a(0) {};
};

class Inherited1 : public Base {
public:
    void add() {
        a++;
    }
};

class Inherited2 : public Base {
public:
    void sub() {
        a--;
    }
};

class Combined : public Inherited1, public Inherited2 {
//public:
//  int& a;
//
//  Combined() : a(Inherited1::a) {};
};

int main() {
    Combined obj;

    obj.add();
    obj.add();
    obj.sub();

    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Inherited1*>(&obj)->a << ' ';     // -> 2
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Inherited2*>(&obj)->a;            // -> -1

    return 0;
}
```

I want to somehow force `add()` method in `Combined` class to use the same variable as `sub()` method without changing `Base`, `Inherited1` or `Inherited2` classes, so my program would print out "1 1".

Is it even possible in that example?

I'm curious because I'm trying to create something like `std::iostream`, just for fun.

Comment: I suspect you may find [virtual base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class) interesting.

Comment: Yes! It's exactly what I've looked for. Thank you very much @WhozCraig!

Comment: Note that you're opening a rancid can of worms here: A diamond inheritance hierarchy. It does have its uses, but be very careful about using this in production code. If Base contains data members initialization rules are un-intuitive. Also, you're opening yourself to some "interesting" ambiguity name lookup situations.